# Laravel 5+ query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

Can any one help me to get laravel join query out put like:

```
LEFT JOIN  table2 ON table2.field1 IN (table1.field1 , table1.field2)
```

This means, I want to join `table2` with any one of the value (that is, **`table1.field1` or `table1.field2`**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.field1 = table1.field2 OR table2.field1 = table1.field1
```

Using Query Builder

```
$records = DB::table('table1')
    ->leftJoin('table2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('table2.field1', '=', 'table1.field1')
             ->orOn('table2.field1' , '=', 'table1.field2');
    })
    ->get();
```

Read more here: [Laravel Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)

Comment: I want to join table2 with table1 based on two columns of table1. Any one of column has matching record, then it should show.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.field1 IN (table1.field1 , table1.field2)` this is incorrect. The correct join format is:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.field1 ON table1.field1 = table1.field2
```

Comment: This is not working. I mentioned a part of big query and it works fine. I want to convert it into laravel query builder format

Answer (score 0):

> you can join two column like that . does this help!

```
 $records = DB::table('table1 as t1')
                 ->leftJoin('table2 as t2', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('t2.field1', '=', 't1.field1');
                    $join->orOn('t2.field1', '=', 't1.field2');
                })->get();
```

see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)  `Advanced Join Clauses`

Comment: If we use two 'on' with more than one condition,  then it will add 'and' with those conditions. That is, out put query will be, t2.field1 = t1.field1 AND t2.field1 = t1.field2. This won't satisfy my requirement.